# Laravel 5.3 Broadcast using Laravel Echo via Pusher using Models Creating, Saving Etc events

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Is there a way to implement this

as documented in this link [Event of Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events)

How can i extend those events to fire broadcast pusher data, rather than making separate events for the model

Answer (score 0):

You could do it a number of ways.  If you want to catch ALL model events you can register a wildcard listener.  In your `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider` in the boot method register the wildcard listener:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Event::listen('eloquent.*', function (array $data) {
        broadcast(new YourModelEventListener($data));
    });
}
```

Or if you want to keep the logic separate for each model you could create a class observer catch all the events and send to your broadcast handler.

Register the observer

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::observe(new MyModelObserver);
    }
}
```

Then in the observer:

```
class MyModelObserver
{
    public function broadcast($method, $model)
    {
        broadcast(new YourModelEventListener($method, $model));
    }

    public function creating($model)
    {
        $this->broadcast('creating', $model);
    }

    public function updating($model)
    {
        $this->broadcast('updating', $model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give the idea where does the broadcast function broadcast channel is?

Comment: See documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/master/broadcasting#broadcasting-events  You would define the channel in the `broadcastOn()` method in the `YourModelEventListener` class that implements the `ShouldBroadcast` interface https://laravel.com/docs/master/broadcasting#defining-broadcast-events

Comment: So I will make a new Event that has an Interface of ShouldBroadcast

where i make an new Listener for the event that i Made

So this will be like a wrapper or something?

like this?

Model Events -> MyBroadCastEvent -> MyBroadCastEventListener?

Comment: i really don't get the idea of the broadcast function,

does the broadcast function calls the EventListener? for all the models or should i Specify a Base Event for that Called event listener

Correct me if im wrong but the idea for me is like this:

Comment: Dive into the docs for events and broadcasting.  They have everything outlined with lots of good examples here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/broadcasting and https://laravel.com/docs/master/events

Comment: i think you mean on the broadcast function

you are passing an event not a listener right?

so ive tried what you gave me but doesn't work as i expected

Answer (score 0):

```
public MyBroadCastEvent implements ShouldBroadcast {
     public function broadcastOn() {
          return ['test'];
     }
}


public MyBroadCastEventListener {
     public function handle(MyBroadCastEvent $event) {
          // should i remove that type hint?
          // then do something here
     }
}
```

then call this?

broadcast(new MyBroadCastEventListener($data)); ?